# Como alimentar um JSON usando "for" JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Eu tenho um json no JavaScript:

```
var cards = [
 {
    name: "Opção 1",
    img: "images/opcao1.jpg",
    id: "1"
 },
 {
    name: "Opção 2",
    img: "images/opcao2.jpg",
    id: "2"
 },
 {
    name: "Opção 3",
    img: "images/opcao3.jpg",
    id: "3"
 }              
        ];
```

Minha dúvida é, como eu poderia editar ou adicionar itens a esse json usando for? O uso do for seria por que eu recebo via Ajax valores para serem alimentados.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entendi. Você quer fazer um lopping com FOR para varrer seu Ajax? Seria isso?

Comment: Na verdade eu quero preencher com mais valores, criando o indice 4, 5, 6 etc

Answer (score 3):

O que você tem é um array, não um JSON. JSON é a apenas a forma de notação de objetos baseado em JavaScript. Dizer que você tem um JSON significa que você tem uma string com a notação JSON:

`const meuJSON = '{"nome": "Usuário"}'`.

Para alimentar seu array, você só precisa fazer `push` nele. O Ajax do jQuery (de acordo com sua tag) já converte o JSON recebido para objeto, exemplo:

```js
var cards = [{
  userId: 0,
  id: 0,
  title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'
}]

$.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log('dados recebidos do ajax:', data)
    cards.push(data)
    console.log('meus cards com o ajax:', cards)
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log('Ops! Um erro aconteceu')
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas no seu código se entende que o json que vou receber é da mesma estrutura do array. o JSON que recebo é que estrutura totalmente diferente, por isso a minha dúvida de como setar determinar valor do JSON recebido a uma posição especifica do array